# Add Objects Detected in TensorFlow

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am currently exploring TensorFlow object detection system, I know it can classify say for example 90 objects as a default. I want to add more objects in the detection. What are the basic steps shall I take?

I have found a tutorial in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku) about tensorflow but it only talks about training specifically new objects not adding more objects to the default objects detected in a certain model classifier.

Any kinds of reference are also encouraged. Any help would be very appreciated. I really need this to get working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In summary Steps:
1. get images
2. Resize Images (to same size)
3. Create TF Records
4. Train
5. Test

Many links out there that walkthrough the same
https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-toy-detector-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api-63c0fdf2ac95

https://medium.com/@dana.yu/training-a-custom-object-detection-model-41093ddc5797